# Sending email over SMTP with sendgrid

Tags: php, html, email, sendgrid

I have a html fieldset and a short php file for sending an email via sendgrid when the submit button is clicked.

HTML

```
            <form id="contact-form" action="scripts/mailer.php" method="post">
                <fieldset form="#contact-form">
                    <legend>Contact Form</legend>
                    <label class="input-field-name">Name:<br />
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="name" required/>
                    </label><br />
                    <label class="input-field-name">Email:<br />
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="email" required/>
                    </label><br />
                    <label class="input-field-name">Message Title:<br />
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="header" required/>
                    </label><br />
                    <label class="input-field-name">Message:<br />
                        <textarea class="message-field" type="text" name="message" required></textarea>                            
                    </label><br />
                    <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

require_once('sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php');

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$header = $_POST["header"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $email);
$subject = $header;
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "MY EMAIL ADDRESS");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", $message);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = 'MY API KEY';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
if($response->statusCode() == 202){
    echo "Email sent successfully";
}else{
    echo "Email could not be sent";
}

echo $response->statusCode();
var_dump($response->headers());
echo $response->body();
```

I am hosting my site on GoDaddy and from everything I've been reading I believe that this should work but instead I get http error 500, my site cannot handle this request.

Any ideas of how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: and, of course, this is a bogus `apiKey` .... right ??? if not you know what to do.

Comment: list errors from log file server 500 - Fatal error php

Comment: I dunno Sendgrid's api, but your code seems odd. Why dont you try-catch around the whole thing, catch Exception AND throwable, and see what gives (am assuming you have no proper IDE).  In general, you should code defensively, with plenty of fail-detection/logging etc ... as this is, your are flying without a safety net.\

Comment: @PumpkinBreath Your API key is in the edit history and is still public. You may as well start the process of revoking it, because it is compromised (or you know you can live with it compromised). If I wore a black hat I'd scrape SO for things that look like such keys in the history as well.

Comment: its changed. wont make that mistake again

Comment: The Apache log will show exactly what the problem is.  What does it say?

Comment: Your code does not seem to match [the SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), what are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One of the servers that I administer is with GoDaddy, and when sending emails using SendGrid's SMTP service, it is key to set the following additional fields:

```
$username = 'apikey';
$host = 'ssl://smtp.sendgrid.net';
$port = 587;
```

When setting the username, use the string 'apikey' as shown above, and NOT your actual apikey.  GoDaddy seems to work well when using port 587, which when setting the host to the above, will send your emails securely.

Your emails should work after this.  Good luck.